# Bidirectional Serialization with Linq

Tags: .net, linq, serialization

Anyone know why only undirectional serialization is supported in the Linq designer?

Consider the following example:

Say we have a `Customer` who requested an `Order` containing `Products`. We set the **Serialization Mode** in the Linq designer to **Unidirectional** to enable serialization.

When looking at the code for the `Order` object, the `DataMember` attribute is added to all its internal properties such as `ID`,`OrderNumber`, etc. and also to the `EntitySet` of `Products`, but not to `Customer`.

One can get around this by manually adding the `DataMember` attribute to `Customer`, but this becomes quite cumbersome when there's loads of entities in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial explanation and workaround is given [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/LINQ2SQLNTiers.aspx). Basically, the cyclic dependencies can occur if the serializer isn't sophisticated. A workaround for bidirectional serialization is available for VS 2008 is given for .NET 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Unfortunately Microsoft has failed to add Bi-directional support in VS2010 so this "solution" still stands.